# escape sql keywords a csv file when inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file which contains a lot of sql keywords. How do i escape the keywords?

sample row from the csv file:

```
F   Aabha Hanjura   115 O/o District Fire Officer Chittor Dist . Chittoor AP 500032 500032  Chittoor    AP  9963736976  Ap_Airlt_Pst            ANDHRA PRADESH  AIRTEL
```

This is what my import statement looks like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/kannel/2.csv" INTO TABLE number_data COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: If that is a true sample from your CSV, your columns are not terminated by `','` as your import attempts. `LOAD DATA` requires no additional escaping, as long as fields are correctly separated and enclosed (wherein the enclosure character needs escaping if it occurs inside)

Comment: This appears to be tab-separated, so you would use `COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t'`

Comment: I copied it from my csv file as in a row

Comment: You should only need: `LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/kannel/2.csv" INTO TABLE number_data COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`  though none of the fields in this sample row are quote-enclosed, but they don't appear to have internal tabs either, so that would be fine.

Comment: I had an excel file with 10 lakh rows and 13 columns . I converted the excel file into csv file . Shouldn't the csv file separate the rows by  a comma ???

Comment: Only if you choose a comma as the separator. Excel has an option for that, and tab might be the default choice rather than comma. I don't have Excel to verify, but go through the export steps again to check. It doesn't matter though - MySQL can handle the tabs too with `\t`.